# On the prime spectrum of $R[[X]]$ when the prime spectrum of $R$ is Noetherian

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, power-series, prime-ideals, zariski-topology

All rings below are commutative with unity.

If $R$ has a.c.c. on radical ideals i.e. if $Spec R$ is Noetherian under Zariski topology, then so is $R[X]$, this is  Theorem 2.5 in the following paper by Ohm and Pendleton

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077377788 .

My question is : If $R$ satisfies a.c.c. on radical ideals, then is it true that so does $R[[X]]$ ? If this is not true in general, is there any additional hypothesis on $R$ that would force this ?

Comment: I have no time for a closer look at the moment, but the examples at the end of J. T. Arnold, _Krull dimension in power series rings,_ Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 177, 299-304 might be of interest.

Comment: In the aforementioned paper it is proved the following: If $V$ is a rank one non-discrete valuation ring, then $V$ has Noetherian spectrum, while $V[[X]]$ has an infinite chain of prime ideals, and therefore it does not have Noetherian spectrum.